# Rails URL billing system redirection with params for invoice creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, billing

I'm currently refining the flow for a payment system on a Rails app.

First, they'll see SaaS like pricing tables with the option to choose and buy.

Once they press "Buy Now" for their preferred plan (they're 2 payment resource types: prepaid and postpaid), if a user hasn't filled in their billing address, they will be redirected to fill it in on a separate view(if completed prior, they're directed straight to their invoice view). Upon completion, they will be redirected back to re-pick their pricing plan.

However, for a seamless flow, i'd like to direct straight to invoice creation right after completing the billing address.

What i thought of so far is to store the pricing plan order `params` (which includes the pricing plan id, promo code string, and payment type path) in the session before redirection for later use. I'm wondering how I can use these session params to initiate creation of the invoice and direct them back to it's view, perhaps with the `request.referrer` method?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that you check if user has a billing address in a `before_action` for `InvoicesController#new` (making up names in here, but it doesn't matter that much)

Now, if they don't have an address filled in, what I would do (what I actually do in one of my apps) would be like this

```
before_action :require_address
def require_address
  unless current_user.billing.present?
    session[:after_billing] = request.url
    redirect_to new_billing_path and return
  end
end
```

And then in `billings_controller#create` since you know you sometimes redirect somewhere else you should do something like

```
redirect_to(session[:after_billing] and return) if session[:after_billing].present?
```

Comment: sounds about right - i'll try it out. thanks for the tip!